# Javascript: How can I interact with a TCP Socket API using net.connect properly?

Tags: javascript, sockets, asynchronous, tcp, electron

I'm fairly new to Javascript and am trying to wrap my head around async, promises, etc.

I have an application running a TCP API (non-HTTP) on the localhost. I'm building an Electron app to interact with this API. I need to send a single request to the API every second and retrieve a single JSON object it returns.

I'm able to do this successfully (for while) by running something like this:

```js
const net = require('net');

function apiCall() {
    if (running) {
        setTimeout(() => {
            
            // Send the request
            request = '{"id":1,"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"getdetails"}'
            socketClient = net.connect({host:'localhost', port:8888},  () => {              
                socketClient.write(request + '\r\n');
            });
        
            // Listen for the response
            var response;
            socketClient.on('data', (data) => {
                response = JSON.parse(data).result;
                updateUI(response);
                socketClient.end();
            });

            // On disconnect
            socketClient.on('end', () => {
                console.log('Disconnected from API');
            });

            apiCall();
        }, refreshRate)
    }   
}
```

After running this for an extended amount of time, it appears that the API server is crashing:

```js
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8888
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1146)
```

Unfortunately, I have no control over the API server or its source code. I'd like some clarification on whether my client might be causing the API server to crash by sending requests this way.

- Should I be opening and closing the connection for each request or keep it open and send requests only every second?
- If I should be keeping the connection open, how can I do this, and do I need to worry about keep-alive?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that every time you call `apiCall` you are creating a new socket client and you are not removing the old socket client instances. This is a memory leak and it will cause the application to crash after running for some time

You can keep a running connection instead like below

```js
const net = require("net");
const { once } = require("events");

let socketClient;

function apiCall() {
  if (running) {
    setTimeout(async () => {
      const request = '{"id":1,"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"getdetails"}';

      // Create the socket client if it was not already created
      if (!socketClient) {
        socketClient = net.connect({ host: "localhost", port: 8888 });

        // On disconnect
        socketClient.on("end", () => {
          console.log("Disconnected from API");
          socketClient.destroy();
          socketClient = null;
        });

        // Wait until connection is established
        await once(socketClient, "connect");
      }

      // Send the request
      socketClient.write(request + "\r\n");
    
      // Listen for the response
      const data = await once(socketClient, "data");
      const response = JSON.parse(data).result;
      updateUI(response);
    
      apiCall();
    }, refreshRate);
  }
}
```